# bug: ios app on ipad and ios8 & ios9 quits when loading googleMapsM4B (v. 1.10-2.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, ipad

Issue has been reported only for iPads. The stacktrace shows:

```
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A344)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
Highlighted by Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
com.Tappsi.tappsiuser failed to scene-create after 19.55s (launch took 0.45s of total time limit 20.00s)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 22.530 (user 22.530, system 0.000), 56% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 18.920, 47% CPU

Filtered syslog:
None found


Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x14f16ec10.events
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000019aab8c84 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a996630 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 160
2   CoreLocation                      0x0000000186046dc8 0x186044000 + 11720
3   CoreLocation                      0x000000018604b83c 0x186044000 + 30780
4   CoreLocation                      0x0000000186085f38 0x186044000 + 270136
5   CoreLocation                      0x0000000186083b8c 0x186044000 + 261004
6   CoreLocation                      0x0000000186083ac0 0x186044000 + 260800
7   CoreLocation                      0x0000000186084d0c 0x186044000 + 265484
8   libxpc.dylib                      0x000000019abcd30c _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
9   libxpc.dylib                      0x000000019abcb0b4 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2132
10  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a98586c _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a989b58 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 656
12  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a991930 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
13  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a988c6c _dispatch_mach_invoke + 600
14  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a991930 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
15  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a989274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
16  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a991930 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
17  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a989274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
18  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a985770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a993bb0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
20  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019a99334c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000019ab99478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000019ab99028 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000019aab8c30 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000019aab8aac mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000185878168 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000185875e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001857a4dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   Foundation                        0x00000001867187ec -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
6   Tappsi                            0x0000000100577af8 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 604
7   Foundation                        0x00000001867ff138 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000019ab9bb3c _pthread_body + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000019ab9baa0 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000019ab99030 thread_start + 4
```

And seems to be a problem similar to:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6484

Although it happens always when loading the viewController that implements GMSMapViewDelegate. Hangs between the ViewWillAppear method and the ViewDidAppear method.

Why does it work on iPhone  but not on iPad?

Comment: You can report bugs at the public issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:IosSDK&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles